# how to make ls show hidden files then directories then regular files in order

Tags: linux, bash, ls

Is there a way to get ls to show all dot files including hidden directories first then regular directories then regular files? I have read throughout the ls man page but come up with nothing. I have also searched Super user and although there are some answers to different questions like showing hidden files first or directories first, I haven't found anything quite in this order.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question. After more research I have found a way to get what I want.

Although not the exact order in which I initially wanted in the question, I have found a way to do this with the order: All dirs including hidden, then all dot files then all regualr files. With this in .bashrc: alias d='LC_COLLATE=C ls -la --group-directories-first'. And I'm happy with that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to split it into two commands: this is best done in a script (such as `lssort`), but if you want `ls` always to work this way you can `alias ls=lssort`:-

```
ls -d --group-directories-first "$@"/.*
ls -d --group-directories-first "$@"/*
```

This assumes that a single directory name (which may contain spaces) is given and that it is the last parameter passed. Unfortunately this has two limitations:-

1. The directory must be given: to overcome this you need to scan the parameters to find the last and make different calls if the last parameter is an option or doesn't exist (replace `/` by space in the above calls).
2. If the `ls` options cause a total line (eg `-l`) to be output you will get two totals, one for each call.

The first of these is answered by scripting:-

```
[ $# == 0 ] && lp='' || eval lp="\${$#}"
[ "${lp#-}" == "$lp" ] && sl=/ || sl=' '
ls -d --group-directories-first "$@"$sl.*
ls -d --group-directories-first "$@"$sl*
```

The second requires all the files to be listed in a single command and the output redirected to a temporary file with a succession of `grep` searches, first for `^total [0-9]*$`, then for files beginning with `.`, then the same search with `-v` to list the remainder. Thus is easy if `ls` produces bare file names, but much more complex in the general case, beyond the scope of this answer.

Notes:-

- `ls -d` is needed to avoid the expansion of subdirectories.
- `... && ... || ...` is a more compact form of `if ...; then ...; else ...; fi`.
- `eval` was necessary to make `bash` parse the command line twice: `${$#}` gives an error.